# Disable default view when offering module is disabled

Tags: 7, views

I have the [User IP Log](http://drupal.org/project/uiplog) that displays the logged data using a default view defined in the module; when the module is disabled, the view page becomes broken, throwing PHP warnings and notices.

I would like to disable the default view when the module defining it is disabled, to fix the PHP warnings I get. Is it the right way of handling this? If it is so, what API could be used for disabling the default view defined by a module?

Comment: Committed a fix, see diff at http://drupalcode.org/project/uiplog.git/commitdiff/6d29a2a?hp=7749064410ff27738546af97db8569c31599a1a3">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_disable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) is what you are looking for:

> Perform necessary actions before module is disabled.
>
> The hook is called every time the module is disabled

Remember to do inverse actions with [`hook_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7), which is used when a modules is enabled, install hooks don't fire when a module is re enabled.

Also if you need to track enable/disabling of another module you can use [`hook_modules_disabled()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_modules_disabled/7) and [`hook_modules_enabled()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7)

(it looks like you found it, but adding an answer for others is always good).